# How get connector info in trino?

Tags: apache-spark, trino, apache-iceberg

I have trino and  iceberg connector. But some queries does not work:

```
SELECT * FROM datalake.m_db."my_table$metadata_log_entries";
```

I wonder - is there a way to know what iceberg version trino uses?